# How to switch env(test, prod) when deploying rails app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to setup a staging env for my app on **Heroku**. And everytime I push my repo it deploys/runs the application in `production` mode. What do I need to do to make the app run in  some other mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the last section in this [Heroku article on Configuration and Config Vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#rack_env_and_rails_env).

In brief, though:

```
$ heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Also be careful not to miss the note that accompanies that section:

> You should never set `RACK_ENV=development`, as that will enable reloading and slow down your app’s dyno significantly.